# UIScrollView cancel/stop setContentOffset:<CGPoint>animate:YES animation

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView that I'm scrolling using setContentOffset:animate:YES but if the device rotates I want to be able to stop it.  Is this possible?  Or how would I go about writing my own implementation of the setContentOffset with animation?  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

scrollview.contentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset should stop the scrollView at its last scroll position.

Do this in willAnimateRotationTo..... in your viewController

If you have a UIScrollView sub-class you could do it in setFrame: , this is assuming the frame of the scrollview changes upon orientation change.

Comment: try to use this instead:

    [UIView animateWithDuration:.25 animations:^
    {
        // replacement for setContentOffset:animated:
        self.scrollView.contentOffset = scrollPositionBeforeKeyboardAdjustments;
    }];

Answer (score 0):

try to use this instead:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:.25 animations:^
{
    // replacement for setContentOffset:animated:
    self.scrollView.contentOffset = scrollPositionBeforeKeyboardAdjustments;
}];
```

if you are struggling with the keyboard, see my answer
[How to make a UITextField move up when keyboard is present?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126726/how-to-make-a-uitextfield-move-up-when-keyboard-is-present/21096604#21096604)